# Iptables rule-set so that a docker container can access a service on a host IP

Tags: iptables, docker

I have troubles accessing a host private interface (ip) from a docker container. I'm fairly certain that it's related to my Iptables rules (or perhaps routing). When I add the `--net=host` flag to `docker run`, everything works as expected. Similarly when I specify that the INPUT policy is following a liberal `-P INPUT ACCEPT`, things also work as I would expect. However these are undesirable and unsafe options i'd like to avoid.

Since it's not specific to my services (DNS) I've excluded that from the problem, since searching for that in combination with docker yields in a different (popular) problem area, adding noise to the search results.

Also linking of Docker containers is not a viable option, because certain containers need to be run with the --net=host option, preventing linking and I want to create a consistent situation where possible.

I have the following Iptables rules. A combination of CoreOS, Digital Ocean and Docker I assume.

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

My (relevant) host interfaces:

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.129.112.210/16 brd 10.129.255.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    inet 172.17.42.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And I run a docker container:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --dns=10.129.112.210 debian:jessie # Specifying the DNS is so that the public DNS servers aren't used.
```

At this point I want to be able to use a local service, bound on 10.129.112.210:53. So that the following should yield a reply:

```
$ ping google.com
^C
$ ping user.skydns.local
^C
```

When I run the same command from my host:

```
$ ping photo.skydns.localPING photo.skydns.local (10.129.112.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.129.112.206: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.790 ms
^C
```

My resolv.conf

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.129.112.210
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

The point here is not to access public hosts, but rather internal ones, using the local DNS service available on the host (via another docker instance).

To illustrate it even further (My ascii art design skills surpass my iptables fu, so that should say enough at this point):

```````````````````````````
 ______________________________________________
|  __________________________           Host   |
| |   Docker DNS container   |                 |
|  ``````````````````````|```                  |
|                        |                     |
|     ,----------,---( private n. interface )  |
|     |          |                             |
|     |          |   ( public  n. interface )---
|     |          |                             |
|     |          |   ( loopbck n. interface )  |
|     |          |                             |
|     |          |                             |
|     |        __|_______________________      |
|     |       | Docker service container |     |
|     |        ``````````````````````````      |
|     |                                        |
|     |                                        |
| [ Local host service using DNS. ]            |
|                                              |
|______________________________________________|

  private (host) network interface: eth1 (10.129.0.0/16)
  Docker network interface: docker0 (172.17.0.0/16)
```````````````````````````

I've searched, read and applied different example Iptables configurations, but I know too little of the more "advanced" Iptables rules to understand whats going on and thus to get the desired result.

Output of `iptables -t nat -nL`:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`:

```
1
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `iptables -t nat -nL`? Did you do any packet analysis, say do a ping from the source container and use tcpdump to capture the packets on the host.

Comment: Certainly, thanks for helping so far: http://pastebin.com/TAaT73nk (Didn't fit the comment..) --[edit]--> Updated the link to a pastebin that doesn't expire.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand correctly your problem, but I don't see any rule to allow DNS queries on host. Also, is ip_forward enabled?

Comment: Hi @LaurentiuRoescu. `$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward -> 1` and `-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT` accepts all connections on the _private_ interface. What rules are you missing?

Comment: I think packets from container come from docker0 interface, not eth1. try `-A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: I think you nailed it @LaurentiuRoescu. When I add your line it seems to work. I never figured it was something that trivial.. Could you please add it as an answer to my question? I'd like to reward your answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Container communicates with host using `docker0` interface.
To allow traffic from container add:

```
-A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Dynom, a lesson you might want to take away from this is that logging all your refusals is useful, with eg `iptables -A INPUT -j LOG`.  The stamp `IN=docker0` would have been very useful in working out what rule tweak was needed.  Not to take away from Laurentiu's work, which was excellent - +1 from me!

Comment: For people who use UFW, here is what I did to allow all communication from Docker containers to host: ufw allow in on docker0

Comment: This is wrong. This is allowing packets back TO the docker interface, such as ACK packets and such. The conntrack rule would be better suited here.

Comment: @Otheus It is the INPUT chain, not OUTPUT.

Comment: @LaurentiuRoescu (3 months later). "To allow traffic _from_ the container" you said, but then you provided a rule which filters the _container's_ INPUT chain, not the host's.  Your rule would allow packets from one container to reach another container. But the OP was to reach a service running on the _host_. (or a specific IP on the host, afaik)

Comment: @otheus This rule is added on the host, not on the container, so it will not affect INPUT chain on container. It will allow packets arriving on host via docker0 interface (from containers).

Comment: I had to use the following rule instead for docker compose to work: `-A INPUT ! -i eth0 -s 172.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered very similar situation but adding `-A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT` will open all accesses over my eth0 interface of docker host to containers which is absolutely not what I intended.

And since I noticed that my container just had limited access(say only port 22) to host interface instead of totally shut down from host network, I reviewed my iptables rules and found a rule in chain IN_public_allow which should be responsible for this. The rule is `-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT`. So I added similar rules to allow my container to access other host ports desired, which I think could be a bit more precise way to open host network access to containers.

Comment: `-i docker0` should ensure that this will not affect traffic which does not arrive via the docker0 network.  Your grammar is unclear though.  Perhaps you were saying that outgoing access from docker hosts via eth0 was enabled, which might be true.  I agree that more targeted rules are possible opening only as much as you need.

Comment: @mc0e "-i docker0 should ensure that this will not affect traffic which does not arrive via the docker0 network" sounds incorrect, especially the word _via_. Instead, _at the docker0 network_ is more precise.